# Real-time audio convolution with AudioKit for stereo impulse response

Tags: ios, core-audio, audiokit

I am trying to figure out if AKConvolution in AudioKit when provided with 2-channel impulse response and mono-channel input outputs 2-channel output response? I want to know what happens in the background. Another thing is: Is there a way to read content of audio output from AudioKit?

Answer (score 0):

AKConvolution can't do that out of the box, but I don't think it would be that hard to alter it to do so. Not sure I understand the follow up question, but best to leave SO with one question at a time.

Here's the source:
https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/tree/master/AudioKit/Common/Nodes/Effects/Reverb/Convolution